# visual basic 2015 wmi set default printer

Tags: vb.net

I created a form with 1 combobox that is populated with installed printers on local network. The default printer is selected when the form is load. When I select another printer i want to validate with a button to be the default printer. Anyway, I searched the net and what I founded is not working (possibly is older answer, not for visual basic 2015). The printer selected is not set to default. "prndf" is the new default printer. I will post here the code:

```
        Dim strComputer
        Dim objWMIService
        Dim col
        strComputer = "."
        objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

        col = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name = 'prndf'")

        For Each objPrinter In col
            objPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter()
        Next
```

Comment: are you just printing a standard like document?

Comment: none. I have hundreds of files : doc, docx, xls, pdf, ...I have 6 printers very aglomerated. I put the printer chosen offline, i print all with a soft who send all type off files, and when i get the printer ready (free) i send mine documents. After that i put the first printer back to default

Comment: your code is correct, are you sure the name of printer ?

Comment: i named all. they are retrieved OK to combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Put this function in your class and called with `SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterName)`.

```
<DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function SetDefaultPrinter(Name As String) As Boolean
End Function
```

Comment: Dllimport underlined with red: Declaration expected.

Comment: You have to add `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` to the top of your source file; or put full name of attribute like this : `<System.Runtime.InteropService.DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>`

Answer (score 1):

I've also ran into this issue. After many searches I found a post somewhere with the solution:

```
Public defaultPrinterNameHardcoded As String = "\\Printserver01\P20451"
DefaultPrinter.DefaultPrinterName = defaultPrinterNameHardcoded

Public Class DefaultPrinter

#Region "GetDefaultPrinter"
    <DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint:="GetDefaultPrinter", _
         SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
         ExactSpelling:=False, _
         CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Shared Function GetDefaultPrinter(ByVal pszBuffer As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
                                              ByRef BufferSize As Int32) As Boolean

    End Function
#End Region

#Region "SetDefaultPrinter"
    <DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint:="SetDefaultPrinter", _
         SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
         ExactSpelling:=False, _
         CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Shared Function SetDefaultPrinter(ByVal PrinterName As String) As Boolean

    End Function
#End Region

    Public Shared Property DefaultPrinterName() As String
        Get
            '\\ Go through the list of printers and return the default one
            Dim lpsRet As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256), chars As Integer = 256
            If GetDefaultPrinter(lpsRet, chars) Then

            End If
            Return lpsRet.ToString
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            '\\ Go through the list of printers and if you find the one named as above make it the default
            If Not SetDefaultPrinter(value) Then
                Trace.WriteLine("Failed to set printer to : " & value)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```